# Highlight UL LI Active Menu Item

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple horizontal menu. What i am trying to achieve is:

1) On load, the Home menu item has a background colour
2) When a menu item is selected, its background colour is highlighted

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <div class="home">Home</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="contact">How to Contact Us</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="products">About Our Products</div>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="home-section">
    Welcome to Home
</div>

<div class="contact-section hide">
    Welcome to Contact Us
</div>

<div class="products-section hide">
    Welcome to Products
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tabs ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.tabs li {  
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;   
    text-align: center;
    color: #B84DFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.home').on('click', function () {
    $(".home-section").show();
    $(".contact-section").hide();
    $(".products-section").hide();
});

$('.contact').on('click', function () {
    $(".home-section").hide();
    $(".contact-section").show();
    $(".products-section").hide();
});

$('.products').on('click', function () {
    $(".home-section").hide();
    $(".contact-section").hide();
    $(".products-section").show();
});
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/dWbx5/10/

Comment: Just a side hint: If you add your classes `.home`, `.products` etc to your `li`, the whole nav box is clickable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just use the click event and assign a class to the element that is clicked:

#### jQuery:

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function(){

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

#### CSS:

```
.tabs li.active
{
    background: #b84dff;
    color: white;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWbx5/12/)

---

### Edit:

As [**@techfoobar**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/921204/techfoobar) pointed out, you could save a line of code and change the jQuery to:

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

---

### Edit 2:

To make the content change more concise, you could do something more like this:

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function(){

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $("div.tab").hide();
    $("div."+$(this).find("div").attr("id")+"-section").show();

});
```

I added a class `.tab` to each of the content divs to make it easier to select them. I then hide all of the divs and show the one with the className that matches `.[child div ID]-section`. And that's all the code you need.

**Note that I changed all of the `<div>'s` `class="home", etc` to `id="home"`.**

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWbx5/20/)

Comment: A slightly more efficient way would be: `$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass("active");` - instead of removing the class from all tabs and then applying to self.

Comment: Thanks guys, accepted David's answer. Is there any way to shorten the hide/show of the DIVs?

Comment: @David - :-) It isn't just about saving one line of code. We are eliminating one selector parsing and resolving (since `this` is already resolved), Secondly, this will work even if we have multiple tab sets on the page. Thirdly, this avoids removing the active class from an element we are going to add the class to immediately afterwards anyway. In any case, readability is king, so your original solution should be more than sufficient. :-)

Comment: @techfoobar Haha fair enough. In my mind, "saving a line of code" == "saving the time and resources devoted to that code" :)

Answer (score 4):

You can add a class `active` to your CSS:

```
.tabs li.active {
    background-color: #444;
}
```

then you can add and remove this class from the menu like this:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

---

Actually, I'd suggest you to shorten your code using `data-*` attribute:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li data-section="home-section" class="active">
        <div class="home">Home</div>
    </li>
    <li data-section="contact-section">
        <div class="contact">How to Contact Us</div>
    </li>
    <li data-section="products-section">
        <div class="products">About Our Products</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

then jQuery:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    var section = $(this).attr('data-section');
    $('div.'+section).show().siblings('div').hide();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dWbx5/19/)**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and clear explanation, accepted David's answer. Is there any way to shorten the hide/show of the DIVs?